# Why doesn't string copy between two char pointers work?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I am trying to copy a string from one char * to another, and do not know why the copy does not work.

I am writing a linked list program -- `Linklist` -- and there are two `char *` pointers involved. Each points to a `struct Node` as follows:

```
struct Node
{
    char * message;
    char * text;
    struct Node * next;
};

typedef struct Node * Linklist;
```

I have written a function which has two parameters to create a new `LinkNode`:

```
Linklist create(char *message,char * text)
{
    Linklist list =(Linklist)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    //the message changes after the sentence but text is right.
    if(list==NULL) printf("error:malloc"); 
    list->message=message;
    list->text=text;
    return list;
}
```

In main:

char *message is"helloworld"

char *text is"test"

I watched the message in gdb,after malloc. The message changed to "/21F/002", but text is still "test"

I added `const` before message, but it doesn't work.

Can anyone can tell what is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there more to this? What other setup is there in the function itself?

Comment: How are you calling `create`?

Comment: @MoatazElmasry that is in the original question

Comment: ok I add more details , it's really strange

Comment: oh I see. so using this malloc statement you are defining a list with exactly one Node, right?

Comment: Can u write a use case where the values change?

Comment: The staement `list->message=message;`, in English, reads: make the pointer `list->message` point to where the pointer `message` points to. If, somewhere down the road, you change the contents of the memory pointed to by either object, the change is reflected by examining data through either object.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that strings in c don't work the same way.  Here is how you copy a string:

```
Linklist create(char *message,char * text)
{
    Linklist list =(Linklist)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    //the message changes after the sentence but text is right.
    if(list==NULL) printf("error:malloc"); 

    list->message = malloc(strlen(message)+1);
    if(list->message==NULL) printf("error:malloc"); 
    strcpy(list->message,message);

    list->text = malloc(strlen(text)+1);
    if(list->text==NULL) printf("error:malloc"); 
    strcpy(list->text,text);

    return list;
}
```

Of course you have to be careful here, make sure message and text are not coming from the user or you risk buffer overflow vulnerabilities.

You can use strncpy() to solve that issue.

Answer (score 2):

you must allocate the storage for your pointers message and text and then copy the string.